# Internet Explorer tries to save script on Ajax Form jQuery plugin submits

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery-forms-plugin

My problem is that when I try to submit a form with jQuery Form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), with `contentType: script`, I get "Save as" pop-up on IEs, that tries to save my response script.

Example code:

```
$("#vendor_edit").ajaxForm({dataType: "script"});
```

Response is JavaScript, that is properly executed on all the other browsers, but IE tries to save this file "vendors.js". Any idea, what might force IE to trigger this pop-up?

Comment: What is the contentType of the response?

Comment: Is this specific to the IE on your machine? If yes, have you checked your browser settings to download instead of open files? Check the Confirm after download option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
$().getScript( url, function(data, textStatus){
    if (typeof(data) === "object"){
        eval(data);  //i.e if you're planning to execute your script
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that was tricky. Response type matters indeed, it needed to be "text/plain" to stop triggering Save As dialog, instead of "application/javascript" for Explorer.

Also, I had to wrap script "textarea" tag, exclusivelly for Explorer to make eval(response) work for some crazy reazon. All other browsers can handle it without texterea wrapper, but IE has a problem with that (I have seen this solution used by Dojo and copied it).